# SQL Server Error Invalid Object Name

Tags: sql-server

```
Dim sConnection As String = "Data Source = svr1066; Initial Catalog = 
  PFSEditTest; Integrated Security = SSPI;"

myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 
PFSEditTestTable(DateFiled, PersonReporting, 
PhoneNumber, PriorityLevel, EffectiveDate, EditType, EditFileName, 
BillingEntity,QueueAssignment, System, SystemNote, FormTypes, BillTypes, 
PayersNote, Payers, Examples, DescriptionOfEdit, CompletedPieReceived, 
WFIDate, WFIPerson, DueDate, CompletedDate, Method, AssignedTo, Status, 
EditNames, TestExamples, TestCriteria)Values (@DateFiled, 
@PersonReporting, @PhoneNumber, @PriorityLevel, @EffectiveDate, @EditType, 
@EditFileName, @BillingEntity, @QueueAssignment, @System, @SystemNote, 
@FormTypes, @BillTypes, @PayersNote, @Payers, 
@Examples, @DescriptionOfEdit, @CompletedPieReceived, @WFIDate, @WFIPerson, 
@DueDate, @CompletedDate, @Method, @AssignedTo, @Status, @EditNames, 
@TestExamples, @TestCriteria)

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I'm trying to insert values into my test database on a server.  I've looked at other posts and I don't see where in SSMS there is an Intellisense option under Edit.  I'm probably missing something.  I've tested the query using the SQL Server Object Explorer and it executes correctly with this query: SELECT * FROM PFSEditTestTable run on this database: PFSEditTest.

Comment: And the question is? Post actual code. I see a missing  end quote and not sure how you assigned values to parameters

Comment: How do I get the query to execute correctly from within my code, not just in the SQL Server Object Explorer?  I also do have a DataGridView that connects correctly but within the code, it doesn't.

Comment: That is a VB question, edit your question and tag it accordingly to receive pertinent views. Also, add your question in the post, not as comments. I could help with parameter values assignation, but you loose me with de grid, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think I'm on the right trail now.  Don't have it all working correctly but starting to see where the issues were.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, the string that you assign to the SQL command, is name of a stored procedure that is going to be executed. In this case, you are not using any stored procedure, so you need to define the type of your command.
Add this statement before calling the ExecuteNonQuery statement to resolve the error:

```
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: CommandType.Text is the default: "The default is Text.". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt VB would have compiled with the missing quote but that's all I see without more information.

```
Dim sConnection As String = "Data Source = svr1066; Initial Catalog = 
  PFSEditTest; Integrated Security = SSPI;"

myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO 
PFSEditTestTable (DateFiled, PersonReporting, 
PhoneNumber, PriorityLevel, EffectiveDate, EditType, EditFileName, 
BillingEntity,QueueAssignment, System, SystemNote, FormTypes, BillTypes, 
PayersNote, Payers, Examples, DescriptionOfEdit, CompletedPieReceived, 
WFIDate, WFIPerson, DueDate, CompletedDate, Method, AssignedTo, Status, 
EditNames, TestExamples, TestCriteria)
Values (@DateFiled,   --<-- Values was flush with )
@PersonReporting, @PhoneNumber, @PriorityLevel, @EffectiveDate, @EditType, 
@EditFileName, @BillingEntity, @QueueAssignment, @System, @SystemNote, 
@FormTypes, @BillTypes, @PayersNote, @Payers, 
@Examples, @DescriptionOfEdit, @CompletedPieReceived, @WFIDate, @WFIPerson, 
@DueDate, @CompletedDate, @Method, @AssignedTo, @Status, @EditNames, 
@TestExamples, @TestCriteria)"  --<-- missing quotation mark

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```